# Find users and their missing values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, left-join

I have a table like below:

```
declare @t as table
(
    userid int,
    val int
)

insert into @t(userid, val) values
(1,1),
(1,2),
(1,3),
(2,3),
(2,4),
(3,1),
(3,2),
(3,3),
(3,4),
(6,1),
(6,2),
(6,3),
(6,4)
```

userid 3 and 6 has all possible values in the val column (1 to 4) but not all the users.

I wish to find the users and their missing values from the above table using the LEFT JOIN and the result of the query for the table above should be like below:

```
userid, val
1,      4
2,      1
2,      2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `cross join` the distinct `userid`s and `val`s, and then `left join` the resulting dataset with the original table to find the missing tuples:

```
select u.userid, v.val
from (select distinct userid from @t) u
cross join (select distinct val from @t) v
left join @t t on t.userid = u.userid and t.val = v.val
where t.userid is null
order by u.userid, v.val
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3d3465f280f356cd236af442c83b108e)**:

```
userid | val
-----: | --:
     1 |   4
     2 |   1
     2 |   2
```